# Learn C# on mac?

Tags: c#, macos

Is mono the only route , any specific visual studio like editors that you recommend?

Comment: I recommend MonoDevelop or SharpDevelop, both freebie C# development tools, both are great for learning and what not. As far as mac goes I'd recommetn going with Mono. www.mono-project.com , you can get the tools and the library from there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without meaning to state the obvious and miss the point, if you mean a Mac computer rather than a Mac OS, you could install [bootcamp](http://www.apple.com/macosx/features/bootcamp.html) or use [parallels](http://www.parallels.com/) to run windows on the Mac and then use Visual Studio (there are also free versions of [Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/Express/))

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, mono is really your only option, unless some undergrad somewhere has developed some very experimental thing I don't know about. As for an IDE, well I believe the only thing half way stable that will work right now on Mac OS X is Monodevelop:

http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Feb-07-2.html

I mean, you could run Parallels and develop your code on a Windows VM with Visual Studio and as long as you follow certain guidelines about portability, you could use VS to develop your mono apps. Although, you probably might as well get familiar with Monodevelop. It would be interesting to see if SharpDevelop ever gets ported.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could also try [Silverlight](http://silverlight.net/)...

Pro:

- It is an official Microsoft implementation, so it is more likely to work
- Its support for recent stuff like C# 3.0 is much better

Con:

- It is browser-only, Silverlight apps do not run standalone
- You won't get the whole .NET Class Library, only a subset, so it is somewhat limited
- You won't get Visual Studio on a Mac

For IDE, I suggest [<s>Eclipse Tools for Microsoft Silverlight</s>](http://www.eclipse4sl.org/download/) (apparently it is Windows-only at the moment) you should use MonoDevelop or SharpDevelop or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Use Xamarin Studio IDE. 
https://xamarin.com/mac

Uses Mono and C#. It has any features you might expect from a modern IDE and combines with XCode for GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Mono is pretty much your only route right now, though there are incessant rumours (I wouldn't give much thought to them, though) that Microsoft is planning to port C# to Mac in the future.  I'd be very surprised if that happened, though.

As for IDEs, I can't help there... If I want C#, I stick to Visual Studio (run it through Parallels or BootCamp, if you really want to use VS).

**Edit:** As Graham points out, there is Cocoa#, but I'd caution that simply because the project has stalled, and there's unlikely to be much future for it. :(

Comment: I agree those are just rumors. Best case scenario is that Microsoft will work more with Miguel to improve Mono, but that isn't necessarily likely either.

Comment: True... they seem to go through "phases" of wanting to help out with Mono, and not wanting to help out with Mono.  I prefer it when they're going through the former phase :)

Answer (score 1):

I would go the virtualization route, either Parallels or VMware Fusion. Both will run Windows XP and Visual Studio very well on a modern Mac. Windows has the best tools for .NET and C# development and it only makes to use them, especially when you're just starting out.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual Box is my new favorite and open source (means free) VM software. Don't pay for Parallels. Also, with BootCamp, you have to reboot the machine to switch between Windows and OS X, so Virtual Box is the way to go.